# Converting dat file into array

Tags: python

I am having a dat file which contains data of the form:

0.23548 0.34938 0.54311 0.20902 0.52414 0.323418 1

for each observation and separated by each line. How would one convert this into an array with the first 6 variables as X's and the last variable as Y?

Thank you again!

Comment: Please be more specific. Is the "dat file" a text file with the .dat file extension? Are all those numbers on one text line, separated by spaces, and you have multiple text lines? Just what do you mean by "the first 6 variables as X's and the last variable as Y"? Would a two-dimensional list for X and a one-dimensional list for Y be sufficient? (i.e. X[0][0]==0.23548, X[0][1]==0.34938, etc., Y[0]==1].) Have you tried any code of your own?

Comment: Thanks for answering some of my questions, but some questions are still outstanding. For example, the format of the desired answer is not yet clear.

Comment: Hi Rory, the file is indeed a .dat extension file, having multiple lines where the first line contains the 6 X's and 1 Y and so forth. I am hoping to convert it into a 2 dimension array as mentioned by mpurg below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a bit unclear, but I'll try to answer anyway.

If the input file has the following structure (without the 1st and 3rd line):

```
X1      X2      X3      X4      X5      X6       Y(1-6)
0.23548 0.34938 0.54311 0.20902 0.52414 0.323418 1
X7      X8      X9      X10     X11     X12      Y(7-12)
0.23548 0.34938 0.54311 0.20902 0.52414 0.323418 1
```

then the following code should work.
It returns a list of tuples (Xn,Yn).

```
points = []
for line in open("file.dat", "r").readlines():
    fields = map(float, line.split())
    xs, y = fields[:-1], fields[-1]
    for x in xs:
        points.append( (x,y) )

print points
```

Comment: Thanks that certainly help a lot! :)